# Parsing CSV from XML document

Tags: python, xml, csv

I need to parse some CSV data from inside a XML document ([TMX map format](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/)) using python, but I am stuck.

I want to use the standard svg and ElTree modules, if possible, and I must use Python 2.7.

This is a snippet of the XML document I am working on:

```
<layer name="Foreground" width="60" height="60">
    <data encoding="csv">
        0,0,0,0,0,1264,1265,1266,1267,
        1268,1269,1270,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    </data>
</layer>
```

This is the snippet of code I use to open the file and try to parse the CSV data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

self.tree = ET.parse('town.tmx')
self.root = self.tree.getroot()
self.bg = []

for layer in self.root.findall('layer'):
    self.data = layer.find('data').text
    self.reader = csv.reader(self.data)
    for row in self.reader:
        for col in self.reader:
            print col
            self.bg.append(col)
```

But printing every element results on this:

```
['0']['', '']['0']['', '']['0']['', '']['0']
```

So, I tried to replace

```
self.reader = csv.reader(self.data)
```

with

```
self.reader = csv.reader([self.data])
```

But now get the error:

```
csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Looking up the CSV module docs it is suggested to apply a parameter to the open() function, but it is obviously not possible here.

I tried to use [itertext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) instead of text to get the data, like this:

```
for layer in self.root.findall('layer'):
    self.data = layer.find('data')
    self.string = "".join(self.data.itertext())
    self.reader = csv.reader([self.string])
    for row in self.reader:
        for col in self.reader:
            print col
            self.bg.append(col)
```

But I get the same errors.

My guess is that the ElTree findall function is replacing the EOL characters with the wrong format, but I don't know how to proceed from here...

Comment: What would csv data look like if it was extracted correctly from the snippet of XML in your question? How many rows is in it? If there's only one, you should [edit] your question and add a snippet with at least two.

Comment: The information in the [TMX map format](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/) link [doesn't say much](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/#data) about how the data is formatted when it's `encoded="csv"`. Do you have a better reference? Otherwise, without a more complete example of an actual data, it's all guesswork...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve your goal using your first code option with slight changes:

It seems that the problem is with how `self.data = layer.find('data').text` looks. It contains a lot of whitespaces that are not needed (tabs, newlines, ...).

By replacing:

```
for layer in self.root.findall('layer'):
    self.data = layer.find('data').text
    self.reader = csv.reader(self.data)
    for row in self.reader:
        for col in self.reader:
            print col
```

with:

```
for layer in self.root.findall('layer'):
    self.data = layer.find('data').text.strip()
    self.data = [x.strip() for x in self.data.split("\n")]
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in self.reader:
        for col in row: # I replaced self.reader with row
            print col
```

bg will look like:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1264', '1265', '1266', '1267', '', '1268', '1269', '1270', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '']
```